# Common .mp4 codec format for web and mobile phones

Tags: video, video-streaming, android-video-player, iphone-video

I have a website and mobile app(for iOS and Android) for e-learning. For web i am using JWPlayer. Many users reporting that they face video freezing or buffering issue.But i have checked in my chrome browser it only buffer even faster internet connection.
  So i want a common .mp4 codec format for both web and mobile(iOS & Android) and suggest me a best video convertor for conversion.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going about the problem the wrong way. If your player is playing video, you're not using a wrong codec to begin with. You might have encoded the video with the wrong settings. Questions on Stack Overflow are supposed to be related to programming problems, so your question is off topic here, unfortunately. I'd recommend you to read this JWPlayer documentation: [MP4 Video Encoding](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28838/mp4-video-encoding) — it explains in great detail what you should look for when encoding for web streaming.

Comment: That being said: The most common encoding configuration to suit mobile devices would be H.264 / MPEG-4 Part 10 (AVC) video encoded at the Baseline profile, possibly in a container with the MOOV atom moved to the beginning (e.g. with [qt-faststart](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/11/12/how-to-make-mp4-progressive-with-qt-faststart/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **I believe that MP4 with code H.264 is the best to follow, referring to the last link below**

I have made some research however I'm stilll looking for the best, but for now

- http://www.indianprice.com/mobiles/articles/272-best-video-format-for-cell-phones.html
  it says 3gp more popular for old ones
- http://www.freemake.com/blog/put-videos-onto-any-mobile-phone-how-to/ it says MP4 is already the most supported by the following settings video format: MP4

  - video codec: H.264 or MPEG4
  - audio codec: AAC or MP3
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video  | That's the best reference to rely on to compare and apparently its H.264 codec